# c++ syntax of define member function that take in int and return pointer to in at outside of the class

Tags: c++, syntax, pointer-to-member

i have a problem in my c++ lab assignment ,i been searching google and i tried with this syntax and it won't show unqualified-Id compile error

```
typedef int (list::*find)(int val);
{
    return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]
The declaration at header file

```
class list {
public:
int *find(int val);
}
```

what is the syntax of define a member function that take in int and return pointer to in at outside of the class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: There is never a semi-colon on a function definition before the `{`. Remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the correct syntax:

```
int* list::find(int val)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

The function declaration isn't that of a function pointer, which is what it seems you are trying to do, but a function that returns a pointer to an integer.

The general syntax of a member function defined outside a class is:

```
ReturnType Class::FunctionName([OptionalParameters]) [OptionalQualifiers]
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: as you are trying to go for the general case you should also mention qualifiers (eg `const`)

Comment: @tobi303 mentioned.